# Log header value in service class

Tags: kotlin, header, metadata, grpc

I have a grpc application written in Kotlin. There is a requirement wherein I need to fetch the client-id info  present in header metadata and log in my service class. The current structure is I have interceptor which has the header data, controller which has access to only request and it invokes service class. Is there any way by which I can do this by using any utility classes etc as I can not pass metadata to controller/ service, it would require a signature change which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the client-id via gRPC context.

Here is an example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-kotlin/issues/85#issuecomment-626181107